# Cassandra data model design for notifications functionality

Tags: model, cassandra

Need some help with design of a data model for notifications. So, I'd like to use Cassandra, and have a web page where I'd like to store notifications for users f.e. :

- received a message from
- user xyz voted your photo
- etc...

User would have to get range of last notifications and delete single notification. So I need a optimal schema (50% of reads vs. 50% of writes ??).

My idea below... (what do you think?? what about keys an sorting by timestamp):

```
notifications {
   john : {
       111-1123-3242-9202 : {type: 'newmail'; ...; timestamp: 321948293849}
       555-1123-aaac-ccc3 : {type: 'voted'; ...; timestamp: 321948293433}
   }

   anna : {...}

   ...
}
```

Really thanks in advance !

Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming "notifications" is your CF, and "john", "anna", etc are row keys.

Assuming the data for each notification is relatively small or never needs to be updated, I suggest that you use timestamps for column names and put the whole serialized notification (perhaps as json) in the column value. This will let you get the last N notifications very efficiently and allow for easy deletion of individual notifications.

Using [pycassa](https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa), the fetch query and delete might look like this:

```
def get_notifications_for(user):
    cols = notifications_cf.get(user, column_count=10)
    return map(json.loads, cols.values())

def delete_notification(user, notification_timestamp):
    notifications_cf.remove(user, columns=[notification_timestamp])
```

I'm assuming here that you've set your comparator to be `LongType(reversed=true)`, which means your notifications will be stored in reverse chronological order if you're using timestamps for column names.

Comment: hmm... I've some question again: is't safe to use Long as column type in this usecase? Theoretically it's possible to generate duplicate columns names. I'm working with Hector & Java and generate time with System.currentTimeInMillis(). Of course I can change to TimeUUID but not sure if I have to.

Comment: Yes, if you're worried about collisions, use TimeUUID instead. That would work perfectly well.

Comment: sure thing. But I'm using Java and Hector client so I've to use com.eaio.uuid.UUID - only one implementation which guarantees uniqueness. But it's only one issue with this UUID. After initializing an object, you can't get a time value !! :) And I've to store a timestamp somewhere in a column. As I know you're a Python coder so it's not your case. Thank you.